# Selecting all the shapes in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need to select all the shapes in a given cell. 
I wrote this code but its generating error.

```
Dim sh as shape
For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
If Not Intersect(Range("B2"), sh.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
    sh.SelectAll   'Error
End If
Next sh
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You mean in a given sheet?  What error does it give?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook  Object does not support this property or method. Although its selecting a single shape if using  "select"  but not more than two

Comment: You should get a `type mismatch` before that - `shp` should be `shape` so you can cycle through each shape in the activesheet shapes.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook It was a typo,  Its shape only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SelectAll` will select all shapes on the sheet.  To do that you'd use:  `ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll`.

To select specific shapes you need to select them without replacing the previous selection.

`Shape.Select` has an optional argument `Replace`.

> (used only with sheets). True to replace the current selection with
>   the specified object. False to extend the current selection to include
>   any previously selected objects and the specified object.

All you need to do is cycle through the shapes and add them to the selection if they're in cell `B2`.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim sh As Shape

    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(Range("B2"), sh.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            sh.Select False
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) your solution worked perfectly as I wanted it.

Comment: Damn it.  I've just levelled up and my life bar hasn't reset.... I'm still old.  I hate these gamified forums. :)